# How to get rid of these spaces?

Tags: html, css

i have [these](http://jsfiddle.net/aUCvN/4/) tabs.

There's border-spacing that is useful between tabs. but they should be deleted from left and right to make tabs width equal to lower box width. How do i do that??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `border-spacing: 2px 0px`, and add this:

```
.tabs li + li {
    border-left: 2px solid #fff
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/aUCvN/6/

The [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) will work in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

*(although the rest of your code does not appear to work in IE7)*

Comment: +1. Yeah, that's a much better solution than using pseudo classes.